# Error 91 after software update/reinstall

Tags: excel, vba

I'm getting "Error 91: Object variable or With block variable not set" when attempting to run simple code.  This code is run on several machines.  One machine is now throwing error 91 after having several applications updated or reinstalled; Excel may or may not be one of the applications that was reinstalled.  My machine, on which the code runs smoothly, has Excel 2010 (14.0.7143.5000).  The machine making problems has Excel 2010 (14.0.7015.1000). I've checked and found no missing library references.

The following (standard export-pdf) code is the problem.  The error is thrown when the "OutlApp" object is referenced in the second With block.

I'm not an expert programmer, barely amateur.  Any help would be appreciated.

```
Function ExportData()
Dim PrintRange As Range
Dim IsCreated As Boolean
Dim PDFData As String
Dim OutlApp As Object
Dim sh1 as Worksheet
Set sh1 = Sheets("Data")
Set PrintRange = Union(sh1.Range("B4:L70"), sh1.Range("B72:L138"))

PDFData = "F:\DATA\file " & Range("K4").Value & ".pdf"
With PrintRange
    .ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, Filename:=PDFData, _
    QUALITY:=xlQualityStandard, INCLUDEDOCPROPERTIES:=True, _
    IGNOREPRINTAREAS:=False, OPENAFTERPUBLISH:=False
End With

On Error Resume Next
Set OutlApp = GetObject(, "OUTLOOK.APPLICATION")
If Err Then
    Set OutlApp = CreateObject("OUTLOOK.APPLICATION")
    IsCreated = True
End If
OutlApp.Visible = True
On Error GoTo 0
With OutlApp.CREATEITEM(0)  '<---Error 91 thrown here
    .Subject = "DATA PACKAGE " & Range("K4").Value
    .To = Range("I15").Value
    .BODY = ""
    .attachments.Add PDFData
    On Error Resume Next
    .SEND
    On Error GoTo 0
End With
Kill PDFData
If IsCreated Then OutlApp.Quit
Set OutlApp = Nothing
End Function
```

Answer (score 2):

I can't be 100% sure but it seems that the problem is that this line fails:

```
Set OutlApp = GetObject(, "OUTLOOK.APPLICATION")
```

And this line as well:

```
Set OutlApp = CreateObject("OUTLOOK.APPLICATION")
```

So when you get to the line which throws error 91 -- `OutlApp` isn't set. As to why those lines fail, maybe the user doesn't have Outlook installed?

Comment: Outlook is installed, but I think that it was the application that was altered before the trouble started.  My money says that you're correct and that OutlApp isn't set; now I just have to figure out why...

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this (Change it with your With block):

```
Dim Mail

Set Mail = OutlApp.CreateItem(0)  

With Mail
    .Subject = "DATA PACKAGE " & Range("K4").Value
    .To = Range("I15").Value
    .BODY = ""
    .attachments.Add PDFData
    On Error Resume Next
    .SEND
    On Error GoTo 0
End With  
Set Mail = Nothing
```

Answer (score 0):

So, the code ran error-free after a few passes through Windows Update.  @JohnColeman had it correct, that the object variable wasn't being set, but I have zero clue *why* it wasn't being set and furthermore, how updating made everything run smoothly.